# multiple alignment to one style POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a problem assigning multiple alignment to **one** XSSFCellStyle.

it looks like I can only assign an alignment using setAlignment(short) method once and it never changes even if I assign different alignment using the same method.

I have four types of cellstyles (unbold, bold, italic, underline) for the whole woorbook. each cell might have a different alignment (right or left or center) for each type of cellstyles. is there a way I can change the alignment for a cellStyle?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You usually create a separate `CellStyle` object per overall style that you would like to have in your Workbook and then assign the style-object to the cells that should have this style.

So for example you would need separate ones for bold-right-aligned and italic-right-aligned and would assign these to the corresponding cells.

Use `Workbook.createCellStyle()` to create the styles at the beginning of your application and assign them to multiple cells later on.

I.e. do not create a new style per Cell but also do not create new styles for each Cell, but re-use them for Cells that should be styled equally.

See also https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Alignment